# line spacing in the pdf while parsing html in itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

when parsing HTML in iTextSharp the generated pdf has line space which is creating 2 documents

I have tried adding
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.SetLeading(0.0f, 0.1f);
but doesnot works

```
sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.Append("<meta charset='windows - 1256'><div class='div1' border='1' style='width: 2in;height: 1in;border: 1px solid blue;font-size:12px;'>");
        sb.Append("<div size='2' style='float:left'>");
        sb.Append("<span>Nathametha<br>");
        sb.Append("Mohammadhussain<br>");
        sb.Append("Abbasbhai<br>");
        sb.Append("53<br>");
        sb.Append("Paracetamol<br>");
        sb.Append("3</span>");
        sb.Append("</div>");
        sb.Append("<div style='float:right'>");
        sb.Append("</div>");
        sb.Append("</div>");
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());

        //Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(;

        var style = new StyleSheet();
        style.LoadTagStyle("span", "font-size", "2px");
        style.LoadTagStyle("span", "margin-top", "0px");


        Document pdfDoc = new Document(new Rectangle(144f, 72f), 0, 0, 0, 0);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        htmlparser.SetStyleSheet(style);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
         p.SetLeading(0.0f, 0.1f);

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            pdfDoc.Add(p);
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();

            byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
```

This is result i am getting
[image]

Comment: You may have an encoding issue.  A character in the input may be causing the document to appear as if it is split.  Is data unicode?

Comment: please check I have edited the code

Comment: Try : <meta charset="windows-1256">

Comment: didn't work I have edited the code again

Comment: Are you calling the code twice?

Comment: no check the code is not repeated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199507/discussion-between-tatvasoftcorp-and-jdweng).

Comment: When you create a new document what are the units for the rectangle? `new Rectangle(144f, 72f)` It's possible that you're just specifying a really small page (72 pixels long), and it's splitting the content when it reaches the end of the first page.

Comment: I have checked it by increasing height from 72  to 110 px doesn't help still I get space